# text-overflow: ellipsis not working for editable div

Tags: css

I have a table having lots of td of which css are

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
max-width:84px;
padding-left:10px;
```

all work fine but I also have editable div in some td for those **text-overflow: ellipsis;** not working.

They are hidden but no **...** for the content

**EDIT**

Here my HTML I am using to generate the table

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>
     <th>Job Title</th>
     <th>Company</th>
     <th>Email</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>ABC</td>
     <td>XYZ</td>
     <td>Software Engineer</td>
     <td><div contenteditable="true">ABC Corporation</div></td>
     <td><div contenteditable="true">abc@gmail.com</div></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Got some markup for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your elements are nested means you need to apply the style to `td div` as well as `td`. This CSS works for the HTML you have supplied:

```
td div{
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
max-width:84px;
padding-left:10px;
}
```

[And here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UgKrW/)

Comment: I appreciate your effort but when I click on editable div it is not showing the hidden content of editable div. If I removed the css applied on div than it shows the hidden content although it does not shows ellipsis

Comment: Well, at the risk of sounding nitpicky, this is technically a different question - but I agree that you should be able to get at the content on focus.

The most elegant way of doing this would be to use `input` elements rather than editable `divs` - [see this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/UgKrW/2/)

This approach also has the advantage of being more semantically sound, since the `divs` here are presumably acting as input fields.

Comment: I took your css and improve your jsfiddle to get correct result here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepgarg/cmeWZ/)

Answer (score -1):

Add `display: block` to the styles.

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
max-width:84px;
padding-left:10px;
display:block;
```

Comment: Adding display:block to the td elements not only has no effect on the ellipsis, but will cause undesirable formatting - see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UgKrW/1/)